# std::vector as input buffer for MPI nonblocking functions

Tags: c++, vector, mpi

**TLDR**: If your input buffer to a nonblocking MPI peer-to-peer or RMA function is a vector, then at some point pointers to underlying elements will be invalidated (upon vector insertion), causing memory corruption issues if communication operations are not complete.

Consider this function, where I have to copy the input data into a vector, before passing it to `MPI_Issend` (or any nonblocking send):

```
    void TaggedIssend(int tag, int target, int count, const long* data)
    {
        // data
        const long msgq_size = msgQ_data_.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            msgQ_data_.push_back(data[i]);

        // request
        const long req_size = msgQ_reqs_.size();
        msgQ_reqs_.push_back(MPI_REQUEST_NULL);

        MPI_Issend(&msgQ_data_[msgq_size], count, MPI_LONG, 
                target, tag, comm_, &msgQ_reqs_[req_size]);
    }
```

At one point, `msgQ_data_` and `msgQ_reqs_` will be moved (copied over to a new location), and at that point if the sends are not complete, then the program will crash (segfaults will appear at seemingly weird places, and `MPI_Request` object could be rendered invalid upon testing, to name a few issues). Although I use `std::vector` in this particular question, same issues will appear with dynamically resizing arrays. That's why the type of input buffer for MPI communication functions is `const void*`.

**Question**: I am interested to know the techniques to safely use a dynamically resizing array as an input buffer to MPI nonblocking functions.  I am currently pushing outgoing data into a fixed-size buffer, and when it is full, I issue all the sends at one go, and complete them before re-using the buffer. Can anyone suggest a better alternative? 
The reason I used `MPI_Issend` here is because my sends are happening inside a while loop, and I can test-all the sends for communication completion (testing a request associated with an `MPI_Issend` will return true only if a matching receive was posted), and use it to break out of the loop.

Comment: The title is kind of misleading, this behavior is pretty much expected, it's not the fault of `std::vector`. I think a more natural approach is using a map from request to data vector.

Comment: Yes, it's an artifact of the program, not `std::vector`, that's why I wrote `can be`.

Comment: The MPI standard states that the send buffer cannot be modified until the non blocking send completes (e.g. your app `MPI_Wait()` or `MPI_Test()`). Otherwise, anything can happen ... The title is misleading in a sense that it suggests a misunderstanding of the standard rather than a genuine issue.

Comment: Agreed, to avoid any more confusion, I edited the title and clarified the question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am interested to know the techniques to safely use a dynamically resizing array as an input buffer to MPI nonblocking functions.

Use `std::vector::reserve` to allocate enough memory space. Then, if you `push_back` into that `vector`, it is guaranteed not to reallocate until the reserved capacity is not full. This solution is kind of fragile, but it will work if you know the maximum vector size in advance.

Alternatively, you can also send with `MPI_Bsend`, e.g., with some incrementing `tag` argument, and then send this tag back to test that data has been received.